# Search for an object in an array from an index position to the end

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have an array of objects of my class:

```
HumorDiary[] note = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HumorDiary[]>(textt);
```

and I would like to search for an object inside it with certain properties chosen by me.

```
foreach ( HumorDiary diario in note)
            {
                if (diario.Anno == DateTime.Now.Year)
                   {
                        
                            if(diario.Giorno == DateTime.Now.Day)
                            {
                                HumorDiary hd = note.First();
                                                              
                            }
                          
                    }
                 
           }
```

After finding that object, I wish I could create a new loop where I check every single object from the index position where the one I found is, all the way to the end of the main array `'note'`. How could I do?

Comment: use `FindIndex` to find the index of an element in an array

Comment: @TimSchmelter I changed the code, there were errors. However I would like to try to locate the index position of the 'HumorDiary hd' object in 'note', then check a certain property of all the objects from the index of 'hd' to the end of the 'note' array

Comment: As @Jason has mentioned you can use FindIndex to find index and then use Array.Copy to create copy of destination array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-5.0#System_Array_IndexOf_System_Array_System_Object_)

```
var start = Array.IndexOf(note,hd);

for(var ndx = start; ndx < note.Length; ndx++)
{
  // do some check on note[ndx]
}
```

Comment: FindIndex does not accept single-parameter methods

Comment: see my edit, I should have suggested IndexOf instead of FindIndex